# Efficiently compare If variable exists and is not equal

Tags: shell, scripting, busybox

I have a problem with the `sh` script syntax. I wrote a script for my Asus router. The script works perfectly. But I have this line:

```
if [[ "$OldIP" && "$StartIP" != "$OldIP" ]]; then echo OK; fi
```

It should be true ( and execute `echo OK`) only if `$StartIP` and `$OldIP` are not the same. The line works, but I would like to see it done more efficiently. The variables conatain valid IP addresses.

In some instances, `$OldIP` will not be assigned anything (is not initialized). But, if `$OldIP` does not exist, this means they are not the same in my shell!

I do not want the line to do: if `$OldIP` does not exist -> test if they are different -> run `echo OK`.

I do want the line to mean: a) if `$OldIP` does not exist -> end. plus b) if `$OldIP` exists -> test if they are different -> run `echo OK`.

So, I would like to remove  `"$OLDIP" &&` somehow, if possible. Not a real problem; curious to learn :)

Sort of (but it does not work):

```
if [ [ "$OldIP" ] != "$StartIP" ]; then echo OK; fi
```

or

```
if [ $OldIP != "$StartIP" ]; then echo OK; fi
```

which does what I want, but complains when *OldIP* is empty (but works OK)

while

```
if [ "$OldIP" != "$StartIP" ]; then echo OK; fi
```

works but ignores that *OldIP* is empty

Comment: You have two conditions that need to be checked, you need them both logically. However, many languages (including all shell scripts that i know of) will "short-circuit" the logical operators. If "$OLDIP" evaluated to false, the remainder of the expression won't be evaluated since it won't change the logic being tested.

Comment: This sound like premature optimization. Have you profiled the script to make sure that this is really the bottleneck?

Comment: Purely curiosity issue. I would like statement to be:       if [[ "$OldIP" != "$StartIP" ]]; then echo OK; fi   but it ignores non existance state of OldtIP

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, a variable does not exist if it has never been assigned a value, or if it has been `unset`.  A variable with an empty string as value *exists*.

The standard parameter expansion `${variable+value}` will substitute the string `value` when `variable` exists (is not unset or empty).  This could be used to test for existence like this:

```
if [ "${OldIP+x}" = "x" ] && [ "$OldIP" != "$StartIP" ]; then
    # code
fi
```

To test whether `OldIP` exists in `bash`, use the `-v` test:

```
 if [[ -v OldIP ]] && [[ "$OldIP" != "$StartIP" ]]; then
     # code
 fi
```

This would perform the string comparison between `$OldIP` and `$StartIP` only if `OldIP` had been previously set (even if it was set to an empty string).  Note that the `-v` test takes the *name* of the variable.

Comment: `busybox` sh doesn't support `-v`. You can use `[ "${OldIP+set}"  = set ]` there.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sorry, that's me not reading the tags and assuming this was for `bash`. My bad. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I tried something similar in my code and bash complains: line 26: [: missing `]'
 if  [ -z "$nextarg" || "$nextarg" =~ ^-[[:alnum:]]$ ]; then
( test if nextarg is either empty, or a "switch" (a minus and one alphanumeric char afterwards). I wonder what's wrong...

Comment: @user176181 Note the use of `[[ ... ]]` around the test.

Answer (score 0):

I think your script is pretty efficient as is. You certainly aren't spending many cycles on this.

Another way to write the logic:

```
{ test -n "$OldIP" || test "$StartIP" != "$OldIP"; } && echo OK
```

This says "if OldIP is set or if OldIP and StartIP are different, then echo OK.

Remember that `[` is another name for `test(1)` which you can read about with `man 1 test`.

Edit: As Gilles pointed out, take care to avoid creating subshells `( ... )` where they're not needed.

`{ ... ; }` can be used to group commands without executing a new shell.

Brief reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html

Comment: Creating a subshell reduces the performance. `{ test … || test …; } && echo OK` would do the same thing without creating a subshell. It wouldn't be a definite performance improvement over the original (maybe a slight difference one way or the other depending on the shell0.

Comment: Thank you Gilles, how ironic I would actually make it slower! I've updated my answer to reflect your hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash`, you can use a default substitution:

```
[[ "${OldIP:=oldunset}" != "${StartIP?StartUnset" ]] && echo "OK"
```

The syntax `${var:-def}` will evaluate to either the current value of `$var`, or to the specified default (in this case, `def`) if the variable is unset or null.  The value of the variable (if any) is unchanged.

The syntax `${var?message}` will exit with an error code of 1 with a message of `message` if `$var` is unset or null.

If you explicitly need `test`-compatible tests, you can do this:

```
[ ! -z "$OldIP" -a "$OldIP" != "$StartIP" ] && echo "OK"
```

Comment: `! -z "STRING"` is the same as `-n "STRING"`  (or just `"STRING"`)

Comment: Your proposal with `${OldIP:=unset}` fails the value of `StartIP` is `unset`. If these are IP addresses as the name suggests, this won't arise, but it makes the code fragile: what if the script supports host names one day?

Comment: Easily fixed.  I shall do so forthwith.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you ask for:

```
[ "${OldIP:-"$StartIP"}" != "$StartIP" ] && echo "OK"
```

As also this (more complex):

```
${OldIP:+false} || { [[ $OldIP != $StartIP ]] && echo "OK"; }
```